# Seven sevens cryptarithmetic

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

This is not my original, but one of the older puzzles I found in an almost-20-years-old puzzle book<sup>1</sup>. It's definitely not the original of the book's author either, so I can't tell the real original source. When I encountered this for the first time, it took me a whole day to solve to the end.

Complete the following long division. An asterisk may contain any single digit from 0 to 9, except that leading zeros are not permitted.

```
                        * * 7 * *
            ---------------------
* * * * 7 * ) * * 7 * * * * * * *
              * * * * * *
              -------------------
              * * * * * 7 *
              * * * * * * *
              -------------------
                  * 7 * * * *
                  * 7 * * * *
                  ---------------
                  * * * * * * *
                  * * * * 7 * *
                  ---------------
                      * * * * * *
                      * * * * * *
                      -----------
                                0
```

<sup>1</sup> *Fun Math Puzzles for Genius* (Korean), Boo-sung Park, 2001

Comment: Please quote the book you used as a source

Comment: Can you provide an Amazon or Google books link of the book ? Some other link will also do. I can neither find the author nor the book online.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/%EC%9E%AC%EB%AF%B8%EC%9E%88%EB%8A%94_%EC%98%81%EC%9E%AC%EB%93%A4%EC%9D%98_%EC%88%98%ED%95%99%ED%8D%BC%EC%A6%90_1/mTFbMgAACAAJ?hl=en

Comment: Thanks..any idea where one can buy the ebook in English ? Do you know if an English version exists ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I don't think it's been translated to English, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> $7375428413 \div 125473 = 58781$.

I started by noticing that

> $7$ times the divisor is still $6$-digit, so the divisor is at most $142857$; but other two digits times the divisor both become $7$-digit, so they must be $8$ or $9$.

and got the answer with some more efforts (which is too lengthy to write down).

Comment: Not showing your work just because there was a lot of it isn't [how we do things around here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/67864/36023).

Comment: @Bass I apologise for the low quality of my answer. However, I'm not going to update it, as I would rather spend the time doing more creative things. For me, the reward of solving the puzzle is the puzzle itself. Please feel free to post your higher quality answer.